# Javascript VM/Emulator?

Tags: javascript, virtualization, emulation

Way back in the day I used to write 6502 assembly code.  I liked it.  I've never had time, or really a good reason, to learn modern assembler but I feel like it's a useful thing to have done.

I was wondering if I could create a web based VM that had the minimal components to give a similar experience to myself and maybe others.

If this already exists, I'd be happy to get a point to it.  If not, I'm curious if it is reasonbly doable in a few 10's of hours time or so.

The elements I can think of are:

- set of cpu instructions
- program counter
- stack pointer
- array of memory locations
- ROM routines that hook to simulated I/O (div and spans i guess)

Answer (score 3):

http://e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/

http://www.tramm.li/i8080/emu8080.html

http://bellard.org/jslinux/index.html

In any case, yes, although tens-of-hours, not sure about that--depends how accurate you want it to be, I suppose, and how quickly you code. A simple VM would be pretty quick, especially with the existing JS components available these days.

Make them flip the switches, I say, screw this terminal I/O BS.

Answer (score 1):

You ask if it's possible to write an emulator in Javascript.

The answer is 'yes'. Someone has already implemented a complete PC + Linux environment in Javascript. See here: http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Note: Only even attempt to run the above link in a modern browser on a decent machine!

That's not to say it would be easy though! I have no idea how much time it took him, but I imagine it was quite a sizable project.